# SQL Linked Server slow performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm still quite new to database performance and understanding all of the intricacies that management studio does for us behind the scenes so any help or reference to learning material is appreciated.

My issue is I'm writing a query to grab data from a linked server and join it to my local db table to insert particular info. I'm using 2 cte's and joining 2 tables in the cte for the linked server data. I then use sub queries to add columns to my result set so I can filter on a row by row situation. I did it this way because I'm not that good at using PIVOT.

```
    with ap AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT col1
    ,col2 ,col3 ,col4
    from [linkedServer].[db].[dbo].[table] st
    JOIN [linkedServer].[db].[dbo].[table2] vs ON vs.col1 = st.col1 AND vs.col2 = st.col2
    WHERE vs.col3 = '' and ...

    ,pre as (
    SELECT *
    ,COALESCE(
    (SELECT 1 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 2 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 3 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 4 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ) Monday 

    ,COALESCE(
    (SELECT 1 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 2 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 3 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 4 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ) Tuesday 

    ,COALESCE(
    (SELECT 1 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 2 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 3 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 4 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ) Wednesday

   ,COALESCE(
    (SELECT 1 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 2 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 3 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ,(SELECT 4 from ap where sss.col1 = ap.col1 and ap.col3 = '')  
    ) Thursday 

    FROM local_Table sss
    )
UPDATE tar 
SET tar.monday = pre.Monday
    ,tar.Tuesday = pre.Tuesday
    ,tar.Wednesday = pre.Wednesday
    ,tar.Thursday = pre.Thursday
FROM local_table tar
JOIN pre on tar.column = pre.column
```

This takes about 5 minutes to run.

From what I've learned so far my options are to use temp tables or create a view on the linked server so I'm not doing any joins in my query.

Any help in optimizing this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use this syntax with a linked server:

```
select field1, field2
from servername.databasename.ownername.tablename
where field3 = something
```

What happens is that sql server will bring over the entire contents of that table first, and apply the where clause afterwards.  The slow execution time is caused by all that data being transferred.

The workaround is to use openquery.   If you google, "sql server openquery" you will find lot's of examples.

Comment: Will it be not better if he can bring all the rows needed into a local temp table create indexes on that table and then do any needed operations it will reduce the number of calls to linked server will be a lot quicker ?

Comment: Depends on how frequently the data changes and how soon one needs to see the changes.  Besides, you wouldn't bring it into a temp table, you would bring it into an actual table.

Comment: I'll do some research into open queries tonight and let you know how it works tomorrow Dan. Thanks!

Comment: Dan, using the openquery my execution time has gone down substantially. Thank you for the advice. What would be the advantage/disadvantage of using temp tables instead of openquery?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, permanent storage would be in a normal table, not a temporary table.  Where I work, we prefer to re-use data as opposed to maintaining mulitple sets of it.  Having said that, we often find the need to create a table variable or temp table and populate it with data from a linked server.  However, that's just to get specific stored procedures to work properly, not to reduce calls to linked servers.

Comment: @DanBracuk - can you give your source for your claim that `sql server will bring over the entire contents of that table first, and apply the where clause afterwards`. Table statistics are available to the server so it can decide to pass the `where` criteria and bring back only filtered results.